# Setting up jupyterhub docker using one of the jupyter stacks

Tags: python-2.7, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I'm trying to get a Jupyterhub up and running. 2.7 Python kernels are required, so basically whatever in the [docker-stacks repo](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks) would be great. In the documentation,  it mentions that it can work with Jupyterhub using DockerSpawner, but I can't quite see how it all fits together. Is anyone aware of a simple step by step guide to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

To use any docker image first pull that from docker hub - docker pull jupyter/scipynotebook

Now install dockerspawner - pip install dockerspawner

Add necessary lines to jupyterhub_config.py 
(https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner/blob/master/README.md)

The way to use specific docker image this line does the magic - **c.DockerSpawner.image = 'jupyter/scipynotebook'**